# Язык Kotlin, Android. что делает знак подчёркивания?

Tags: android, kotlin, checkbox, listener

Есть объект CheckBox. Добавляем к нему слушателя

```
testCheckBox.apply{
setOnCheckedChangeListener {_,isCheked ->
test=isCheked
 }
}
```

В Java там добавляется слушатель по другому, а тут используется лямбда. Не понимаю что означает знак нижнего подчёркивания и в каких случаях он используется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#underscore-for-unused-variables-since-11)

> Underscore for unused variables
> If the lambda parameter is unused, you can place an underscore instead of its name:
>
> ```
> map.forEach { _, value -> println("$value!") }
> ```

Нижнее подчеркивание использоется для неиспользуемых переменных.
Если параметр лямбды не используется, вы можете поставить нижние подчеркивание вместо его имени:

```
map.forEach { _, value -> println("$value!") }
```

Comment: я думала что в лямдах нужно обязательно указывать тип значений...

Comment: @YulyaUlyanova ахах, я не знаю котлина, просто в доках нашел ;)

Comment: эх...( очень жаль

Comment: @YulyaUlyanova Да не, сейчас кто-нибудь, кто знает выйдет и ответит. XD

Comment: @YulyaUlyanova в kotlin не обязательно указывать тип переменной в лямбде, впрочем как и в java: `testCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener((_, isCheked) -> doSomething());`

Comment: спасибо, я так поняла в Kotlin, когда параметров больше одного то скобки не нужны, как в java?